# Squid as transparent proxy

Tags: networking, proxy, squid

I am trying to configure squid as a transparent proxy. Eventually, I want it to use one of 5 different outgoing IP addresses based on the IP address the request was received on. My configuration currently looks like this:

```
http_port 206.217.196.142:3128 name=3128
acl tasty3128 myportname 3128 src 50.32.253.162/24
http_access allow tasty3128
tcp_outgoing_address 206.217.196.142 tasty3128
```

However when I try to use my proxy, I receive an error from my browser that the proxy is refusing connections. I can ping the proxy server from my client. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you configured iptables to do the transparent redirect to the 3128 port? Also, I think first line should be like `http_port 206.217.196.142:3128 transparent` (v. <3.1) or `http_port 206.217.196.142:3128 intercept`, second `acl tasty3128 src 50.32.253.162/24`